# Remove non printable characters but keep accents (PHP 5.5 to 5.6 issue)

Tags: php, preg-replace, diacritics, non-printing-characters

I want to remove non printable characters and keep french accents like "é".
I'm able to do this in PHP 5.5 but not on PHP 5.6.

On PHP 5.5 :

```
$original = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]/u', '', $original);
```

This works perfectly.
But since my upgrade to PHP 5.6, it returns a blank value !

On PHP 5.6, i use this partial fix :

```
$original = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $original);
```

Non printable characters are removed but accents are removed too.
How can I keep them?

When the variable is saved to SQL, I would like to have "mangé", but it returns "mang" on PHP 5.6 so.

Thanks for help !

Comment: try setting  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Comment: no change unfortunately

Comment: Found my error, it was another thing. Many thanks for the help anyway :)